# How a standard video file is structured under the hood

Tags: video, file-formats

I am new to looking into video file formats, and am wondering what it would take to parse one. To do that, I first would need to understand what the format looks like, so that's what this question is about.

Wondering if one could briefly outline how a video file format is structured, or what it contains. Any [video file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) is helpful, but [WebM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) would be preferred since it is open / royalty free, and modern (which I presume to mean it would be simpler to understand). But whatever file format is simplest to demonstrate the point is best.

The main thing I am looking for is not a detailed specification at this point, just basically *what goes into a video file*. I am used to "static" content like programming language files or image files, but videos are large, streamed files where it needs to handle network issues and syncing and all that, as part of "moving through the file contents". My knowledge consists of "videos are probably sent as chunks of some sort of binary data", but that's it. I would like to know roughly how it gets organized in these different files (again, any one is fine, or a generic example is okay too). What the general features of the file format are.

I would like to be able to take a look at a [WebM parser](https://gist.github.com/mganeko/9ceee931ac5dde298e81), but not sure what the scope of the features are for video files. Basically trying to understand how a video file "works".

Comment: What goes in a video file? Bunch of pictures one after another. Playing these pictures quickly one after another makes it seem like stuff is moving. Having every frame be a complete picture is of course very inefficient way to do it, but that is the simplest way.

Comment: I get that much, but it's not a bunch of image files concatenated together so not super helpful :) Looking for "realistic" features.

Comment: Basically you have have pictures, then describe how the said picture is transformed to the next, and every now and then you have a complete picture(a 'keyframe'). Here is some preliminary reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types
A very basic video file with only pictures concatenated together is just uncompressed video, which is of course the highest quality you can have, but very inefficient in storage.

Comment: @Zavior Only if those individual pictures aren't compressed lossily either.

Comment: Note that unless you are a codec writer you will almost never want to deal directly with a video file. You will generally use some library (libmatroska, AVFoundation, FFMPEG, etc.) to get the frames and metadata for you. You'll then work with the frames and/or metadata and call out to the library to update, change, add, delete, etc. frames and metadata.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parsing a complete digital film is an immensely complex task. Because you mostly ask about WebM – a container format – I’ll concentrate on that.

You always start with individual streams containing the payload data: video (e.g. H.264, VP9), audio (e.g. AAC, Opus) and subtitles (e.g. SubRip, Blu-ray PGS). Tied to those streams is some metadata needed for correct playback. For example the streams need to be synchronized properly.

As a simple example imagine a WebM file containing a VP9 video stream and an Opus audio stream.

The WebM container acts as a wrapper for the VP9 and Opus streams that makes it possible to put them into a single file and still access them conveniently. Also it contains additional data like the types of streams it contains or checksums for error recovery.

Naively you could store the streams one after the other in a single chunk each. Obviously that’s a horrible solution for streaming because you’d have to buffer the complete file before playback can start. That’s one reason why streams are interleaved. The file stores a small chunk of video followed by a small chunk of audio (maybe half a second each) and repeats that pattern throughout the file.

What do you need to parse such a file?

- A WebM parser to process the container and extract the payload streams.
- A VP9 parser (probably as a part of a full VP9 decoder) to process the video stream.
- An Opus parser (again probably as a part of a full Opus decoder) to process the audio stream.

WebM is a subset of Matroska. You can get a full specification of the format on the [Matroska website](https://matroska.org/technical/index.html). The parser you link to seems extremely simplistic on first glance, but it might be a good enough starting point. For a complete implementation you should have a closer look at the reference parser: [libmatroska](https://github.com/Matroska-Org/libmatroska). It’s used for example in the de-facto standard Matroska muxing application [MKVMerge](https://mkvtoolnix.download/).

Btw: “Muxing” is short for “multiplexing”. The long form is rarely used, though.

Answer (score 6):

Video container formats are typically made up of a series of content blocks. A block typically consists of a few marker bytes (important for finding the next block if you get incomplete data while streaming), a type code (metadata, audio data, video data, ...), a length, followed by some amount of data.

The file would typically start with a metadata block. It contains information about the file: is it a single picture, an audio-only stream, mixed video and audio? Are there multiple audio channels (different languages)? What's the resolution of the video? What audio and video codec are used?

After that comes a series of content blocks. Their interpretation is up to the codecs. Audio and video blocks are interleaved so that they can be played back simultaneously. A single video block might contain all the data for one video frame, followed by audio blocks for the audio data for the same time range. But this splitting is up to the encoder, and might be done a different way, too. The audio for several frames might be put into a single audio block perhaps, to save encoding overhead.

The codecs themselves are a different, huge topic.